# How do I link Google Maps Markers to other elements?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Using the [google maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html) (and JavaScript) I have been able to easily display several markers which each have a nice little info window over them.

```
//Create map over USA
map = new google.maps.Map2( document.getElementById('map') );
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(38.95940879245423, -100.283203125), 3);

//Create point, then marker, and then add to map
function create_marker(lat, lng, html) {
    var marker = new GMarker( new GLatLng(lat,lng));
    marker.bindInfoWindow(html);
    map.addOverlay(marker);
}

var html = '<div>this is my text</div>';
create_marker(38.95940879245423, -100.283203125, html);
```

However, I now want to be able to link the "click" of markers to functions which can update other parts of the page as well. For example, I would like to have a sidebar with copies of the marker infowindow content. The same way [google maps shows results](http://www.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=frys,+texas&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=54.22533,79.013672&ie=UTF8&hq=frys,&hnear=Texas&z=7) on the left and markers on the right. I might even want the click of sidebar content to open a given marker infowindow on the map.

The problem is that the [GMarker](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMarker) click event only passes the lat/long - and I'm not sure how I can use that to find the matching div or whatever.

How do I get a unique id/handle for each marker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign an id to each marker and its corresponding element in the sidebar.  Create an event listener to call that id.  Something like this:

```
var html = '<div>this is my text</div>';
var sideHtml = '<div id="1">this is my text</div>';
create_marker(38.95940879245423, -100.283203125, html, 1);
$("#sidebar").append(sideHtml); // Add the text to the sidebar (jQuery)

//Create point, then marker, and then add to map
function create_marker(lat, lng, html, id) {
    var marker = new GMarker( new GLatLng(lat,lng));
    marker.bindInfoWindow(html);
    map.addOverlay(marker);

    GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function(latlng) {
        var div = document.getElementById(id); //access the sidebar element
        // etc...
    });
}
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490266/).

Answer (score 0):

For those interested there is a great example of l[inking dom elements with markers](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/tooltips.htm) given here. Basically you just create a global JS array that holds a reference to each marker object.